# Class returns empty property JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, object, ecmascript-6

I have a simple class:

```
class Build {
    dataFetched = {};

    constructor(id = '') {
      this.id = id;
    }
    
    getData(){
        return request({
            some request
        }).then(({ data }) => {
            this.dataFetched = {...data};
        }).catch(({e}) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }

   showData(){
        return this.dataFetched;
    }
}
```

in a different file i am trying to create an object and call getData as well as showData

```
 let test = new Build(input_data);
 test.getData();
 test.showData();
```

this returns an **empty object**, but if method showData just returns **"this"** the dataFetched property is filled with data from the request.

Not sure what is going on, and would grealty appreciate some help/clarification

Comment: when you call `showData` the promise is not yet been resolved

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia but when i return "this" instead of "this.dataFetched" dataFetched is populated? why is that

Comment: @asynctomas because the dev console is magic (it loads in data as the object is when you expand it, not when you logged it)

Comment: Requests are asynchronous meaning they need time to send the request before they can receive the fetch data. When you run this code at all at once, you are calling `showData` before the request(...).then had time to process your HTTP request. 
 be why you are getting the empty object. When you manually run `test.showData()` after some time has passed, the request completed so you get the data you expect.

 You see the `.then` function that adds the data to dataFetched? That function needs time beofre running. It doesn't get run right away

Answer (score -1):

You need to `await getData()` before calling `showData` as it returns a promise

```
let test = new Build(input_data);
await test.getData();
console.log(test.showData());
```

This must be within an `async` function.

The other option is to *chain* another `then` on to the return - this *doesn't* need to be within an `async` function

```
let test = new Build(input_data);
test.getData().then( () => console.log(test.showData()));
```